# Magento 2 : Admin grid with thumbnail field

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, thumbnail

I have added a custom admin grid using ui component, now I want to add a thumbnail field in the grid. Please help me to do the same..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add below column code in your **ui_component**

```
<column name="image" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Thumbnail">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/thumbnail</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>                    
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Slider Image</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Thumbnail class add code at `Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Thumbnail.php` as below

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Thumbnail extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if(isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            $path = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                    );
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {               
                $item[$fieldName . '_src'] = $path.$item['image'];
                $item[$fieldName . '_alt'] = $item['slider_title'];
                $item[$fieldName . '_orig_src'] = $path.$item['image'];
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }   
}
```

In above code change field name as per your field

Comment: Thanks @prashant .. I need two thumbnail fields in admin grid. For that what I need to do?

Comment: You need to copy column code two time in ui_component file and you need to create two class file one for each

Comment: The above thumnail.php is only used to display the image in admin grid Or Is this have any special purpose while saving a uploaded image @Prashant Valanda.

Comment: No this have any special purpose that is only for display image preview on grid

Comment: [(I too have this thumnail.php file in my module which handling for only a single image and saved in DB),  But Now I have added multiple image fields(like small, medium, large,extralarge images). And having a issue that images are saved in pub/media/myfolder, But failed to save in DB. So am I need to handle this in thumnail.php

Comment: You can not handle this in this file you have to save images in save action of your module

Comment: @PrashantValanda Now the Images are saved both pub/media and my DB

Comment: The above Thumnail.php contains $path= that is the path of the image. Are you saying the path of the image where it  need to store while uploading a image

Comment: Yes that path of your location where are you saving image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72492/discussion-between-sri-and-prashant-valanda).